# Push (change) file on NOT rooted android

Tags: android, startup, galaxy, s5

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 phone (SM-G901F) that is not rooted and I just won't to root it.
It is from T-Mobile network and it has T-Mobile startup and shutdown logos with sound. I don't mind the logos but I just want to mute sound. So I made silenced files (**PowerOn.ogg** and **PowerOff.wav**) and I just want to replace originals at **/system/media/audio/ui** but I don't know how.
I tried it over ADB but I got error:

```
Read-only file system
```

Can someone help me? Is this posible to do without rooting device?

Comment: You have to root it

Comment: There are several ways of mounting /system as read/write but I do not know if they require you to have the phone rooted. Take a look here -> http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110927/how-to-mount-system-rewritable-or-read-only-rw-ro